# MySQL ORDER BY when using name.co.uk or name-something.co.uk

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I have my code where I use

```
ORDER BY domain_name ASC
```

and get results like

```
name-somethinga.co.uk
name-somethingb.co.uk
name.co.uk
papa-alpha.co.uk
papa.co.uk
```

what I would like to know is it possible to get the results like

```
name.co.uk
name-somethinga.co.uk
name-somethingb.co.uk
papa.co.uk
papa-alpha.co.uk
```

Comment: what logic should that order follow? you can do order by desc or asc, but neither will result in what you want. Mostly because it is not clear what you want: giving just one example is by far not enough in this case. Describe *in general* how you want your data to be sorted.

Comment: Is what you're asking for basically how to sort alphabetically? It's very unclear what the desired behavior is here.

Comment: I have added another example. I want the ones without the - in the URL first as these will be the main websites and thus I prefer it sorted that way...

Comment: I updated my answer sqlfiddle link to include your new data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4bc/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that in an alpha sort, dash comes before dot.

You want to order by ONLY the characters to the left of the dot.

So:

```
ORDER BY left(domain_name, locate('.', domain_name)-1 )
```

Here is a SQLFiddle of it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4bc/1

This version shows what you are sorting by:

```
select *, left(domain_name, locate('.', domain_name)-1 ) as sortname
from sites
ORDER BY left(domain_name, locate('.', domain_name)-1 ) ASC;
```

Gives:

```
id  domain_name             sortname
3   name.co.uk              name
1   name-somethinga.co.uk   name-somethinga
2   name-somethingb.co.uk   name-somethingb
4   papa.co.uk              papa
5   papa-alpha.co.uk        papa-alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is DESC, so your statement would be:

ORDER BY "whatever" DESC

Comment: Nope, that is not what the example suggests.

Comment: yeah didn't really notice the name. disregard my answer, Digital Chris seems the be on the right track